# Variables in Python: Add and change variables

Tags: python, variables

I am currently making a game in Python, and now I want to add a store.

I want to do this with a variable. I know how to add variables, and how to change them, but not how to increase or decrease the variable.

I have actually never used variables before. I have read about it, but I don't remember much about it.

```
def level1():
os.system('cls')
gold = 500
print
print 'You have currently',
print (gold),
print 'gold'
time.sleep(3)
level2()

def level2():
print
print 'Congratulation! You completed the quest! You received 200 gold.'
time.sleep(2)
gold =+ 200
print 'You have now',
print (gold),
print 'gold.'
time.sleep(5)
```

And the result is:

**You have currently 500 gold**

**Congratulation! You completed the quest! You received 200 gold.
You have now 200 gold.**

I tried gold + 200, gold += 200, and gold =+ 200, but only the last one worked.

I also tried

```
print 'You have now' + gold + 'gold'
```

But that didn't work for some reason. I also tried with

```
print 'You have now' + (gold) + 'gold'
```

I am not quite sure what's wrong here, and I would appreciate all the help I can get!

Thank you very much.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to add a huge part of my question. I am sorry for that!

==================================================================================

In the store, I will sell multiple items to different prices. Not all of the items will be available in the beginning of the game. 
Therefore I want an item to check how much gold the user have. If the user have under x gold, he can't buy that item.

If the level have reached level 04, that specific item will be unlocked.

Comment: `gold += 200` is the correct syntax.  You might have an error elsewhere.  Can you correct your indentation?  Are these two functions entirely separate?

Comment: `gold =+ 200` just sets `gold` to `+200`, or `200`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `gold += 200` and not `gold =+ 200`.

Secondly, it seems `gold` is a variable that is local to each function, i.e. assigning `gold` to 500 in `level1()` does not set it to that value in `level2`. You need to either pass it in as arguments, or have it as a global.

To pass as arguments:

```
def level1(gold) :
  # do your stuff here
  level2(gold)

def level2(gold) :
  # do your stuff here

# entry point of your application
if __name__ == "__main__" :
  # initialize `gold` here
  gold = 500
  level1(gold)
```

To use a global instance:

```
# global variable 
gold = 500

def level1() :
  # specify that you want to use the global instance of gold
  global gold
  # do your stuff here

def level2() :
  global gold
  # do your stuff here
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't understand much of that if __ name __, so I just went for the global instance. Thank you very much.

As you could see, I forgot to add a important part of my question. Could you please take a look at that aswell? :)

Comment: @StigHetl Please ask additional questions in a separate Stack Overflow question.  (And you should remove the edited addition in *this* question.)